# What are the differences between REPLACE, INSERT, UPDATE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain the differences between REPLACE, INSERT and UPDATE in MySQL?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? REPLACE , UPDATE and INSERT ... They are obviously doing different things.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: `INSERT` inserts, `UPDATE` updates rows where a `WHERE` clause matches, `REPLACE` "works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Comment: I gave this an upvote, for casual/naive users of MySQL this is a useful question, yes you can 'look it up' but I find SO answers often more informative then looking stuff up in a reference manual.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

These are totally different statements.

- **Insert**: Insert new record
- **Update**: Update existing record
- **Replace**: works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

Cheers!

Prasad.